# Html/CSS Show pop up youtube video to full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pen [Morphing Play Button v3](https://codepen.io/kab0086/pen/pozqoyZ)

I am using [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/06aac531b3da3cfec6a6140ad8c3e003) for click to pop up video which has iframe for video.

I successfully make it work but having issue in making it in center of the window.

[image: Before opening video]

Now when i clicked the screen it shows iframe window on extreme right. like this
[image]

When i tried to edit css of `<div class="play-perspective">` 's `top` and `left`values it turned play button also outside of animated circle. I tried to change multiple values in JS too but no luck.

Here is my code

```
<section class="hero-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="margin-top:100px; margin-right:30px; height:506px; width:332px; float: right; background:url(images/Mobile-Screen.png)"  >

<div class="play-backdrop"></div>
<div class="play-button">
  <svg class="play-circles" viewBox="0 0 152 152">
    <circle class="play-circle-01" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="343 343" cx="76" cy="76" r="72.7"/>
    <circle class="play-circle-02" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="309 309" cx="76" cy="76" r="65.5"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="play-perspective">
    <button class="play-close"></button>
    <div class="play-triangle">
      <div class="play-video">
        <iframe width="600" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>     
            </div>
```

I am having Same CSS and JQuery of linked plugin (if required i will post it too). I want to screen look like first image and when i click on play button it expand to window width and custom height.
Please guide me i am having this since yesterday.

Comment: `<iframe width="600" height="400"` <-- This should give you a clue

Comment: tried not working. That width extended to the right which is not visible on screen

Comment: You need to remove those 2 attributes. Set their width / height to 100%. Same for `play-video` and `play-triangle` so they inherit the width and height of the `play-perspective` class. At least, that's where I would start

Comment: @icecub let me try again and get back to you

Comment: If you can't get it to work, please make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code (at least enough to get your current result) so we can work directly with it.

Comment: your best shot in getting a good answer is to provide a working fiddle. Issues like these are really hard to guess out, and you may end up without a solution using SO.

Comment: I also forget to mention it's bootstrap template.

Comment: Well like we said, please make a JSFiddle for us. You can add Bootstrap to JSFiddle perfectly fine.

Comment: Please check edited question with PEN

Comment: It just had to be THAT video huh.. You just HAD to do it!

Comment: I don't know much about JSfiddle or Pen i just created as you guys wanted to see that.

Comment: Well at least I got it working a little bit. Just change `$video-width: 500px` to `$video-width: 100vw` and it works. But it basicly makes it fullscreen which I guess isn't what you intended

Comment: No i want to it be responsive and change it's size according to the screen.